# How to create an XML file in ExtJS 6?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created an ExtJS application in which I have a need to create an XML File. 
I am fetching some information from database and after I want to create an XML file to write that information into it because I want to upload that information in XML file.

Answer (score 2):

**Before you start, it's good to to remember**

- DOMParser

  > DOMParser can parse XML or HTML source stored in a string into a DOM
  >   Document. DOMParser is specified in DOM Parsing and Serialization.
- parseFromString()

  > Creates an instance of a document that contains a Document Object
  >   Model (DOM) tree from a string of serialized XML source.
- createElement()

  > The createElement() method creates an element node. This method
  >   returns an Element object.
- setAttribute()

  > Is used to create a new attribute for an element.

**The scenario I suggest**

- Fetch data from database (in my example below I suppose that you're fetching a list of persons).
- Loop over the returned result and for each record:

  - Create a new person element.
  - Create a new attribute (in the example below I suppose that there is an "*id*" to be used as an attribute).
  - Create as many elements as you need for the current person.
- Send the created XML data to a backend service (a PHP file for example) using AJAX to save it as an XML file on your server. If you'll use PHP, I invite you to use SimpleXML: http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

**The JavaScript code**

```js
function getDataFromDatabase(){
 return {
  people: [
   {id: 1, name: 'John Doe', age: 11},
   {id: 2, name: 'John Roe', age: 22},
   {id: 3, name: 'Jane Doe', age: 33},
   {id: 4, name: 'Jane Roe', age: 44}
  ]
 };
}

function sendXmlToBeSaved(xmlData){
 var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpRequest.status == 200) {
   var result = xmlHttpRequest.responseText;  
   // Do what you want here
   // based on the result returned
  }
 }
 xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "https://www.example.com/javaPhpOrOtherPage", true);
 xmlHttpRequest.send(xmlData);
}

function createXmlData(dbData){
 var strXmlData = "<people></people>";
 var parser = new DOMParser();
 var xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(strXmlData, "text/xml");
  
 // This is the root element
 var peopleElements = xmlDocument.getElementsByTagName("people");

 var people = dbData.people;
 for(person in people){
  if( people.hasOwnProperty(person) ){
   var id = people[person].id;
   var name = people[person].name;
   var age = people[person].age;
   
   //Create one person element
   var personNode = xmlDocument.createElement("person");

   //Create the id attribute
   personNode.setAttribute("id", id);

   //Create the name element
   var nameNode = xmlDocument.createElement("name");
   var personName = xmlDocument.createTextNode(name);
   nameNode.appendChild(personName);
   personNode.appendChild(nameNode);

   //Create the age element
   var ageNode = xmlDocument.createElement("age");
   var personAge = xmlDocument.createTextNode(age);
   ageNode.appendChild(personAge);
   personNode.appendChild(ageNode);

   //Add the created person element to people root
   peopleElements[0].appendChild(personNode);   
  }
 }
 var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
 var strXmlData = serializer.serializeToString(xmlDocument); 
 return strXmlData;
}

var dbData = getDataFromDatabase();
var xmlData = createXmlData(dbData);
console.log(xmlData);
//sendXmlToBeSaved(xmlData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "upload" the xml on a server from a ext application, you should be able to use `Ext.Ajax`. Build up your xml string and append it to the request inside `extraParams`.

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
 url: 'your_domain.com/server_script.php',
 extraParams:{
   xml:'<xml><node>text</nod></xml>'
 },
 success: function(response, opts) {
     var obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
     console.log(obj);
 },

 failure: function(response, opts) {
     console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
 }
```

});

Read more on [extjs docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/modern/Ext.Ajax.html) about options of the request (headers, binary, request type, etc);